# Saving a state with jquery accordion style menu (Maccordion)

Tags: jquery, save, accordion, state

These questions are probably going to seem pretty low end to the experienced, but I'm inexperienced in this area. However, I learn quick and there are some basic things I'm having confusion over.

My situation is that I've implemented Maccordion in a server side script.  Maccordion is an accordion style menu based on jquery that lets you have multiple panels open at the same time.  I start it up by having the following script block in my head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$( ".maccordion" ).maccordion( { active: [], heightStyle: false } );
});
</script>
```

This part works fine.  FYI, the "active: []" part will let me open various menu panes on load.  For example, "active: [0,2]" will open pane one and three.

I want to save the state change of the panels and the Maccordion page at https://github.com/Dattaya/Maccordion/blob/master/README.md gives me the following information on doing this.

**activate**

Triggered when the maccordion has been changed.

```
$( ".maccordion" ).bind("maccordionactivate": function(event, data) {
    data.toggled // headers of the content panels that have been toggled.
});
```

I have no problems making a server side script that can save and restore the state of the panels, the issue I have is to take the above "data.toggled" variable and somehow pass it to that script in the background to save the state of the panels.

I'm guessing the idea is to use javascript and ajax to do this.  How to do this confuses me on several levels.

First, I'm not even sure how I'm supposed to use the snippet above. I've found a lot of snippets out there that kind of explain how to do this, but unfortunately they all assume the reader knows how to insert the javascript properly, and how to call things from events that happen in the web page, etc... I've read tutorials on W3C and other places, looked at source code on all sorts of web pages, but there's something in the logic that is not clicking with me.

Basically what I need to be able to do is take that **data.toggled** variable and pass it to a server side script of my choice without interupting the user ever time they open or closes a panel.

As I write this I've been reading all of the hints that come up in the flesh colored right menu and notice some people saving states with jquery cookie snippets such as:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    change: function(event, ui) {
        //set cookie for current index on change event
        $.cookie('saved_index', null);
        $.cookie('saved_index', $( "#accordion" )
                .accordion( "option", "active" ));
    },
    active:parseInt($.cookie('saved_index'))
});
});
```

I don't have a problem using cookies instead of a db, but it's beyond me how I'd use something like this to save the states of multiple panels.

Anything to help me get this going in the right direction would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First i have added an attribute to each `<h3>` element that indicate it's number in the list of tabs. I named the attribute "data-list"

HTML CODE

```
<div class="maccordion">    
    <h3 data-list="0"><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
    <div >First content</div>

    <h3 data-list="1"><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
    <div >Second content</div>

    <h3 data-list="2"><a href="#">Third header</a></h3>
    <div >Third content</div>
</div>
```

Now you need to capture the "activate" event of the maccordion and then get the element number were toggled send it to the server

```
$( ".maccordion" ).maccordion(  { active: [], heightStyle: false } );

$( ".maccordion" ).maccordion({
    activate: function(event, data) { 
        var listNumber = data.toggled.attr('data-list');
        var toggleState = data.toggled.next().css('display');
            // block = Open
            // none = Close

        //Send the data to the server
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "URL", //This sould be a url of a page 
                      which suppost to recieve the information
          data: { listToggeld: listNumber } //Sent the list number to the server
        }).done(function( msg ) {
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
    }
});
```

1. First look how i bind the active event
2. Then i used the "data" variable which hold the DOM element that just have been toggled, to get the data-list attribute.
3. We get also the state of the tab either it close of opened.
4. Now that we have the element number and were toggled and status we ready to send it to the server with ajax request. [Look here for more information of ajax requests](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[Fiddel Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UeGVn/30/)